# Some contents is not showing in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have created a simple Blog using Rails, it works fine in development environment but it is not working well in Production environment. I deployed my app in Heroku.
The content is not showing in the production mode.
Following is the code I used for the Categories/Index

```
<h1>Categories</h1>

<% @category.each do |cat|%>
    <ul>
        <li> <%= link_to cat.title, {:action => 'show', :id => cat.id} %> </li>
    </ul>
<%end%>
```

Also when i go to developer tools in my browser only the heading Categories is showing and the li is not showing but in the development mode it is showing in the developer tools on my browser. I have no idea what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try checking for javascript errors in the 'production' page using your browser's developer tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem before, it's likely caused by **your Heroku database having no data in it**.

---

The way to resolve this is to use database ["seeding"](http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html):

```
#db/seed.rb
categories = %w(cat1 cat2 cat3)
categories.each do |category|
   Category.find_or_create_by(name: category)
end

$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Categories"
$ git push heroku master

$ heroku run rake db:seed
```

Comment: I was thinking the same :)

Comment: You should write an answer - it's daunting using a new platform for the first time, maybe your input will help too

Comment: Remember Heroku databases don't populate themselves!!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your `categories` table has ***no records*** on the ***heroku DB***. Since the `link` is ***within the loop*** it is not displayed in the view. To easily identify the problem, use the code below

```
<h1>Categories</h1>
<% if @category.present? %>
  <% @category.each do |cat|%>
    <ul>
      <li> <%= link_to cat.title, {:action => 'show', :id => cat.id} %> </li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
<h2>There are no categories at the moment.</h2>
<% end %>
```

Now, since there are no records in the `categories` table, you will see that **There are no categories at the moment.** being displayed.

***Solution:***

You should populate the `categories` table in the ***Heroku DB*** with some records. Now you will see the `link` is being displayed.